# Prove that $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence iff $\forall \epsilon > 0\ \exists N: \forall n > N \implies |x_n - x_N| < \epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, cauchy-sequences

> Let $\{x_n\}$ denote a sequence. Prove that: 
>   $$
> \{x_n\}\ \text{is fundamental} \iff \forall \epsilon > 0\ \exists N: \forall n > N \implies |x_n - x_N| < \epsilon
> $$

Let $P$ be a statement that:
$$
P = \forall \epsilon > 0\ \exists N: \forall n > N \implies |x_n - x_N| < \epsilon\tag1
$$

Let $Q$ be a statement that $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence:
$$
Q = \forall \epsilon > 0\ \exists N \in \Bbb N:\forall n,m > N \implies |x_n - x_m| < \epsilon \tag2
$$

We want to show two things: $P \implies Q$ and $Q \implies P$.

---

$\Box$ Start with $P \implies Q$. Then by $(1)$:
$$
\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists N_1 \in\Bbb N : \forall n > N_1 \implies |x_n - x_{N_1}| < \epsilon \tag3
$$

At the same time:
$$
\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists N_2 \in\Bbb N : \forall m > N_2 \implies |x_m - x_{N_2}| < \epsilon \tag4
$$

If we now choose $N = \max\{N_1, N_2\}$ both statements are true and we obtain:
$$
\forall\epsilon > 0\ \exists N =\max\{N_1, N_2\}: \forall n, m> N \implies 
\begin{cases}
|x_n - x_N| < \epsilon \\
|x_m - x_N| < \epsilon \\
\end{cases}
$$

Consider the sum of the inequalities:
$$
|x_n - x_N| + |x_m - x_N| < 2\epsilon \\
|(x_n - x_N) - (x_m - x_N)| \le |x_n - x_N| + |x_m - x_N| \\
|x_n - x_m| < 2\epsilon
$$
Now if we choose $\epsilon = {\epsilon_0 \over 2}$ in $(3)$ and $(4)$ we get:
$$
\forall \epsilon_0>0\ \exists N =\max\{N_1, N_2\} : \forall n, m > N \implies |x_n - x_m| < \epsilon_0\ \Box
$$

---

$\Box$ Proceed to $Q\implies P$. This is where I got stuck. So far I've got that if a sequence is Cauchy then it must be bounded.

---

What should be my steps to show the second implication? Also I'm not quite sure about the first part is correct, could you please confirm/reject it as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Q\implies P$ is evident from definition of Cauchy sequence:

$$ \forall \epsilon > 0\ \exists N \in \Bbb N:\forall n,m \ge N \implies |x_n - x_m| < \epsilon $$

if we let $m=N$, we get $P$.

while for $P\implies Q$, by carefully picking $N$ so that for given $\epsilon>0$, $n>N$ implies $|x_n-X_N|<\cfrac {\epsilon}2$, we have:

$|x_n-x_m|\le|x_n-x_N|+|x_m-x_N|<\epsilon$, when both $n, m>N$

hence $(x_n)$ is Cauchy or Q is true.